# Create User Role in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Thanks in advance

> I need to set Role in particular users depends on their Role. I had
>   try to goggled many websites but I did not get clear idea about this
>   Roles. I need to implement this Role concept in my mvc project.

**Controller:-**

```
 [AllowAnonymous]        
    public ActionResult EditableUserDetails( )
    {

        if (!Roles.RoleExists("test"))
            Roles.CreateRole("test");
        var UserName = Session["UserName"].ToString();
        Roles.AddUserToRole(UserName, "test");

        var linq = (from db in EntityObj.Users
                    where db.IsActive == true
                    select new EditableUserDetails
                    {
                        UserId = db.UserId,
                        UserName = db.UserName,
                        Password = db.Password,
                        Category = db.Category
                    }).ToList();   

        var data = linq.ToList();           
        return View(data);

    }
```

If I run this code I got this following error:-

[image]